# trocar separador decimal em python

Tags: python, gráfico, locale

Como faço para trocar o separador decimal de ponto para virgula e em seguida gerar um gráfico? Usei o comando que segue, não deu erro, mas o grafico continua com ponto como separador decimal

```
   import locale
   loc = locale.getlocale()
   locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "pt_BR")
```

Comment: Você está usando um arquivo de dados? Está gerando esses dados aleatoriamente? Mostre a saída dos seus dados. Edite sua pergunta para que ela seja reproduzível por todos, assim poderemos te ajudar de forma mais eficiente. Abraço!

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. O código é bem simples, estou querendo plotar o gráfico de uma série temporal, porém com separador decimal como vírgula já que o artigo é em portugês. Eu importei as bibliotecas pandas, matplotlib e a locale. Em seguida leio a base de dados em CSV (pd.read_csv('dados.csv', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True) e manda plotar o gráfico. Mas continua gerando o gráfico com ponto.

Answer (score 0):

Se você precisar de uma string, você pode simplesmente substituir o ponto por uma vírgula com o `replace()`, porém creio que não seja muito viável se precisar fazer isso várias vezes.

```
numero_com_ponto = 123.45
numero_com_virgula = str(numero_com_ponto).replace('.', ',')
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Saberia me dizer se tem como fazer esse processo de replace ao importar a base de dados*? Outra dúvida seria se a transformação do tipo de uma variável float para string não comprometeria a geração do gráfico?

*dados = pd.read_csv('dados.csv', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True).